# pip install mysql-connector InstallationError

Tags: python, mysql

when i pip install mysql-connector i got this

```
   > Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector   Downloading
    > mysql-connector-2.2.3.tar.gz (12.0MB): 12.0MB downloaded   Running
    > setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector/setup.py) egg_info
    > for package mysql-connector
    >     
    >     # Python architecture: 64-bit
    >     # Python ARCH_64BIT: True Installing collected packages: mysql-connector   Running setup.py install for mysql-connector
    >     Not Installing MySQL C Extension
    >     Unable to find Protobuf include directory.
    >     # Python architecture: 64-bit
    >     # Python ARCH_64BIT: True
    >     Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
    > tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
    > 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
    > 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9uM0JD-record/install-record.txt
    > --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    >     running install
    > 
    > Not Installing MySQL C Extension
    > 
    > running build
    > 
    > running build_py
    > 
    > creating build
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/network.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/abstracts.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/protocol.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/custom_types.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/conversion.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/optionfiles.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/constants.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/errorcode.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/pooling.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/authentication.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/connection.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/charsets.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/version.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/cursor.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/dbapi.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/utils.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/catch23.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/errors.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/locales
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/locales/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/locales
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/locales/eng
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/locales/eng/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/locales/eng
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/locales/eng/client_error.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/locales/eng
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/base.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/introspection.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/compiler.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/client.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/operations.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/validation.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/features.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/schema.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/django/creation.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/django
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/fabric
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/fabric/connection.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/fabric
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/fabric/balancing.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/fabric
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/fabric/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/fabric
    > 
    > copying lib/mysql/connector/fabric/caching.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysql/connector/fabric
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/result.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/crud.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/statement.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/dbdoc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/expr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/errorcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/authentication.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/charsets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/protobuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx/locales
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/locales/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx/locales
    > 
    > creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx/locales/eng
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/locales/eng/__init__.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx/locales/eng
    > 
    > copying lib/mysqlx/locales/eng/client_error.py ->
    > build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mysqlx/locales/eng
    > 
    > running build_ext
    > 
    > Unable to find Protobuf include directory.
    > 
    > # Python architecture: 64-bit
    > 
    > # Python ARCH_64BIT: True
    > 
    > ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
    > tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
    > 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
    > 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9uM0JD-record/install-record.txt
    > --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector Storing debug log for failure
    > in /home/liuchenhui/.pip/pip.log
```

and traceback in the file pip.log

```
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9uM0JD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 707, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 715, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9uM0JD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-connector
```

**so i would like to know how to solve this problem
if it is need to install mysql c or others ?
how can i make it?
(are this describe enough? can i show it ?)**

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Ended up installing older version:  pip install mysql-connector==2.1.3

Comment: Is this ok?i will try it.

Comment: I have downloaded the source code, complied it and installed locally, and it succeed

Comment: Cool... Put ur solution in an answer and select it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had several different problems with installing the python mysql-connector, and have tried many different solutions, some very complicated.  Finally, this simple line that has worked the most reliably for me:

```
pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

From a user comment in the official documents. :)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html

This worked for me to install it under W10, and python 3.6